# FB Graph API query doesn't work in PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Graph API: 2.4
PHP SDK: "facebook/php-sdk-v4": "~5.0"

I'd like to get details about a page via PHP and the PHP SDK.
Using the query:

```
$response = $fb->get('/' . $sPageID . '?fields=posts', $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
```

returns the posts with a good amount of data. But unfortunately wrong values:
The limit 25 for likes for instance applies here. So even if one post should have 150 likes, if I do an `count ($post['likes'])` I only get 25 as a result.

So I tried to change my query and according to the Graph Explorer
this seems to be working fine:
`PAGE_ID/posts?fields=likes.limit(100),message,comments,shares,picture,link,type`

Now I can't get this transformed into my PHP call. 
I receive timeouts and

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException' with message 'Unable to convert response from Graph to a GraphNode because the response looks like a GraphEdge. Try using GraphNodeFactory::makeGraphEdge() instead.' in ...

Is this possible with one query in PHP or do I have to run multiple queries, one for each post?

Answer (score 7):

I found this [answer](https://github.com/SammyK/LaravelFacebookSdk/issues/73), and if because the end of point of this request is a GraphEdge, so try this:

```
// Get basic info on the user from Facebook.
try {
    $response = $fb->get('/' . $sPageID . '?fields=posts', $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);

} catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    dd($e->getMessage());
}
$getGraphEdge = $response->getGraphEdge();
```

I hope this help you.

Regards.

Comment: Seems like I can't use `getGraphEdge` but `getGraphNode` - does this depend on the `/posts` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Newer PHP SDK versions have the `getGraphList()` method, `getGraphEdge()` is for the earlier, even though it wasn't documented.

Comment: This answer would be better if you explained the difference between the two, preferably with a link to documentation where the explanation exists.

Comment: Update: Just use `getBody()`.