# Getting users Facebook friends with php throws exception

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to get a list of the users friends with php but it keeps throwing an exception the code is the same from Facebook for developers docs 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.0/user/friends

here is my code

```
$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => APP_ID,
        'app_secret' => APP_SECRET,
        'default_graph_version' => DEFAULT_GRAPH_VERSION,
        //'access_token' => '{'.$fbToken.'}', // optional
    ]);

try {
            $response = $fb->get('/friends', $fbToken);
        } catch(FacebookExceptionsFacebookResponseException $e) {
            echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        } catch(FacebookExceptionsFacebookSDKException $e) {
            echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }

        $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
```

And here is the stacktrace of the error

```
[03-Jul-2018 07:29:33 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException' with message 'Unable to convert response from Graph to a GraphNode because the response looks like a GraphEdge. Try using GraphNodeFactory::makeGraphEdge() instead.' in /facebook/Facebook/GraphNodes/GraphNodeFactory.php:224
Stack trace:
#0 /facebook/Facebook/GraphNodes/GraphNodeFactory.php(93): Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphNodeFactory->validateResponseCastableAsGraphNode()
#1 /facebook/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php(289): Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphNodeFactory->makeGraphNode(NULL)
#2 {main}
  thrown in /facebook/Facebook/GraphNodes/GraphNodeFactory.php on line 224
```

Comment: Have you tried what the error message suggested?

Comment: @Steffi No but won't that mean that I have to change the code in the Facebook sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$graphNode = $response->getGraphEdge();
```

Quite old so i did not mark it as duplicate: [FB Graph API query doesn't work in PHP SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31759593/fb-graph-api-query-doesnt-work-in-php-sdk)